# Adding text to textAngular from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, textangular

I wana add text inside textAngular from ng-repeat like this:

```
 <text-angular required ta-max-text="600" ta-min-text="15" ng-model="form.comment">{{x.text}}</text-angular>
```

Where `{{x.text}}` is text from ng-repeat... Any solution for this?

Comment: where's the `ng-repeat` directive?

Comment: Its wrapping `text-angular`

Comment: can you provide a simple jsfiddle with the full source?

Comment: It is simple to understand I just need to have text inside `text-angular` from `ng-repat` so I can edit the text...

Comment: Does your `form.comment` holds any value, if it does content between text-angular tags will be replaced with the value of  `form.comment`. In other words, `{{x.text}}` won't be displayed

Comment: You are right, thanks!